# monotonic function( no numpy and arrow) using only lists and loop

Tags: python, list

monotonic_function
input: list
output : returns alist of Booleans(True/False) for example :

```
    sequence_monotonicity([1,2,3,4,5,6]) return [True,True,False,False]
    sequence_monotonicity([1,2,2,3]) return [True,False,False,False]
    sequence_monotonicity([1,0,-1,1]) return [False,False,False,False]
```

the rules are :
I cant use all , any / or import anything(like numpy)

if a(n-1) <= a(n)  is correct it returns True into the first place of list, else return: False

if (an-1) < a(n)  is correct it returns True into the second place of the list, else : returns false

if a(n-1) >=a(n)  is correct it returns True into the 3rd place of the list, else: returns: False

if a(n-1) > a(n)  is correct it returns True into the 4th place of the list, else : returns False

i tried to do it without numpy "thedumbest" way possible but i dont get correct answers

this is what i tried :

```
    def true_false_checker(x):
        if False in x:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def sequence_monotonicity(l):
        z =[]
        x = []
        for i in range(1,len(l)):
            if l[i-1] <= l[i]:
                x.append(True)
            else:
                x.append(False)
            if true_false_checker(x) == True:
                z.append(True)
            else:
                z.append(False)
            if l[i-1] < l[i]:
                x.append(True)
            else:
                x.append(False)
            if true_false_checker(x) == True:
                z.append(True)
            if l[i-1] >= l[i]:
                x.append(True)
            else:
                x.append(False)
            if true_false_checker(x) == True:
                z.append(True)    
            if l[i-1] > l[i]:
                x.append(True)
            else:
                x.append(False)    
            if true_false_checker(x) == True:
                z.append(True)    
        return z
'''
```

Comment: Please provide some data, what is your input and what's your output?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
def seq_mon(l):
    r = [True]*4
    for x in [a-b for a,b in zip(l[:-1],l[1:])]:
        r[0] &= x<=0
        r[1] &= x<0
        r[2] &= x>=0
        r[3] &= x>0
    return r
```